# How to add a "favorability" direction variable to a linear model in R?

Tags: r, regression

I'm working on a modeling problem using multiple regression in R. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to build a linear model to capture a certain kind of data.

My data consists of three variables: Year, Demand (in units), Species. The data represents results for a single state in a country.

Here's my dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(
  Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005),
  Demand = c(14, 63, 55, 78, 34, 19),
  Species = c("Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog"))
```

I'm attempting to predict the amount of demand on the state's market for the given species like this:

```
m1 <- lm(Demand ~ Species, data = dat)
```

However, I want to add another variable to the dataset titled `MarketFavorability` which is how favorable the country's total market is towards the species in question as measured by a bump in demand for that species. Basically, this predicts the state's demand based on the country's overall demand change.

Here's my question: How does one code for that in a linear model? Would the answer be to create another variable that categorically names whether the market is favorable for a certain species and the "push" in demand that's expected from that favorability? That might look something like this:

```
dat$MarketFavorability <- c(2, 5, 8, 4, 3, 9) # Represents the national bump in demand for the species.
dat$MarketFavorabilityDirection <- c(Dog, Cat, Cat, Cat, Dog, Cat) # Represents the bump's "direction".
```

And then the linear model would look like this:

```
m2 <- lm(Demand ~ Species + MarketFavorability + MarketFavorabilityDirection, data = dat)
```

Am I doing this right? Any recommendations for the best way to capture fluctuations in the market overall in my linear model? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to *estimate* something about the effect of market favorability or do you just want to include it in the model as a known factor?

Comment: I'd like to understand if it's a statistically significant variable for my model, but I'm not sure how to plug both the bump and the direction of the bump into the model.

Answer (score 0):

How about to introduce interaction term?
Considering interaction term is sometimes useful to explain variation of response.

```
d <- data.table(
  Year = 2000:2005,
  Demand = c(14, 63, 55, 78, 34, 19),
  Species = c("Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Dog"),
  MarketFavorability = c(2, 5, 8, 4, 3, 9),
  MarketFavorabilityDirection = c("Dog", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Cat")
)

m3 <- lm(Demand ~ Species + MarketFavorability + MarketFavorabilityDirection + MarketFavorability * MarketFavorabilityDirection, data = d)
summary(m3)

# Call:
# lm(formula = Demand ~ Species + MarketFavorability + MarketFavorabilityDirection + 
#     MarketFavorability * MarketFavorabilityDirection, data = d)
# 
# Residuals:
#          1          2          3          4          5          6 
#  8.327e-17 -1.905e+00  6.348e-16  1.524e+00 -3.089e-16  3.810e-01 
# 
# Coefficients:
#                                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)                                        147.5714     5.8275  25.323   0.0251 *
# SpeciesDog                                         -24.8095     3.1414  -7.898   0.0802 .
# MarketFavorability                                 -11.5714     0.6598 -17.537   0.0363 *
# MarketFavorabilityDirectionDog                    -173.5714    10.6394 -16.314   0.0390 *
# MarketFavorability:MarketFavorabilityDirectionDog   31.5714     3.5533   8.885   0.0713 .
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.469 on 1 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.9981,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9907 
# F-statistic: 133.6 on 4 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.06479
```

Comment: Could you explain how this addresses the problem that was asked?

Comment: A question was about a recommendation for better model in order to explain variation of response. So my recommendation is generating another new explanatory variable like interaction term from existing variables then "demand" can be explained better than before. I misunderstood a question wrongly?

Comment: I read the question as much more specifically asking how to create a "market favorability" variable by summarizing the data by country, to "predict the state's demand based on the country's overall demand change."

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. mmm, ok, I must understand what I'm not understanding an original question. Question was not how to model demand. How to create a variable named "market favorability" was a question..... I don't know then. Sorry for my contamination to answer space...